# How to call Cucumber scenario using beforehook in another scenario

Tags: angularjs, protractor, cucumber, hook

I'm using protractor with cucumber.
I have a scenario in which I need to call one other scenario as the pre-condition.
Pattern is like this:

Scenario1 :

```
@test1
Scenario: first scenario
```

Scenario2 :

```
@test2
//Need to call the first scenario as the pre-condition
Scenario: second scenario
```

Here, I want to use the cucumber hook.
So, my hook file is like this:

```
this.Before({tags: ["@test2"]}, function (event, callback) {
        console.log('call the first scenario');
        this.feature(tags: ["@test1"]);
        callback();
    });
```

Can somebody tell me how can I do 
"this.feature(tags: ["@test1"]);"

Answer (score 0):

In Cucumber you do setup using a Given.

In your case you need to write a Given that does what your first scenario does. The question now becomes how do you do this elegantly

If you implement all step definitions as single calls to helper methods this becomes fairly easy. As each step definitions is just a single call you can turn scenario 1 into a series of calls e.g. foo, bar, baz

Now for scenario 2 and its given you write a new method `scenario 1` that just repeats the calls e.g.

`def scenario1
  foo
  bar
  baz
end`

By doing this you have taken the problem out of Cucumber and into the programming language you are implementing your steps. This approach has a bit of a steep learning curve, you have to

1. Learn how to write helper methods in the language of your choice
2. Learn how to share helper methods between your features

I can't help you with that as you are using JAVA and I use Ruby. I do know its much more complicated in Java than Ruby. However its definitely worth learning how to do this, as this will give your the ability to make all of your cukes simpler, and give your opportunities to make them faster as well.

Comment: Thanks @diabolist, I agree with your answer, but the requirement for me is different that I can’t do any changes to the framework or to the step definitions. I know it should be possible to call scenarios as pre-conditions as in cucumber they have a “beforeScenario” hook, but the question here is how to do it. Otherwise, in all other places I follow the given method for pre conditions. Thanks for your input.

Comment: If you can't break that constriction then you can't use Cucumber effectively. You need to talk to the people who are making those restrictions and work with them to remove them, or write suitable step definitions to meet your needs. You can't expect Cucumber to support bad practice.